# Use with_options with the Rails form helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have form that has :prompt => "Select" on many inputs:

```
f.select :country, :prompt => "Select"
f.select :city, :prompt => "Select"
...
```

Is there a way to wrap this using with_options and DRY it up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work :)

```
f.with_options :prompt => "Select" do |form|
  form.select :country
  form.select :city
end
```